# How to get the returnvalue from stored procedure which uses GetStoredProcCommand with an object array of parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures, sql-server-2005

I have an SP below which returns either 1 or 2. This is good.

```
IF EXISTS(select 1 from Emp where empId = @empId)
    return 1
ELSE    
    return 2
```

In the test code, I can do like below and get the return value displayed on the screen. I am using framework 2.0.

```
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("AddEmpTest", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empId", txtEmp.Text.Trim());

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ReturnVal", SqlDbType.Int);
        cmd.Parameters["@ReturnVal"].Direction = 
        ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

        int retval = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        myLabel.Text = Convert.ToString(cmd.Parameters["@ReturnVal"].Value); 
        // returns 1 or 2 based on the input          
        con.Close();
```

However, how to do the same for the below code where parameter array is used? How to add this ReturnVal and how it can be retrieved in the code behind.

```
object[] procParam = { empId, deptId, firstname, lastname, salary, managerId, etc…) 

return DbHelper.ExecuteScalarData("AddEmpTest", procParam); // this object returns null, 
//but it should return either 1 or 2


public static object ExecuteScalarData(string spName, params object[] parameterValues)
{
       DbCommand cmd = GetAuthCommand(spName, parameterValues);
       return db.ExecuteScalar(cmd);       
}

public static DbCommand GetAuthCommand(string spName, params object[] parameterValues)
{
       DbConnection con = GetConnection();
       DbCommand cmd = db.GetStoredProcCommand(spName, parameterValues);
       cmd.Connection = con;
       cmd.CommandTimeout = m_CommandTimeout;
}
```

Comment: Just as a test, could you try: `cmd.Parameters.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Direction == ParameterDirection.ReturnValue).Value` ?

Comment: forgot to mention that I am using framework 2.0. and i need to add the return parameter with direction as returnvalue before th eline db.ExecuteScalar(cmd) right? Here cmd is of type DbCommand. Once this is done, i need to retrieve the return value from DbHelper.ExecuteScalarData("AddEmpTest", procParam);

Comment: Strange that nobody knows how to add a returnvalue parameter to an object array to Storedprocedure!!

Comment: The library (Enterprise Data Library or something like that) you're using is very old, your code is not pure ADO.NET, if you'd use ADO.NET you'd get more hands if you need a hand